# Qual a melhor maneira de fragmentar um projeto Django em apps?

Tags: python, aplicação-web, django, organização-de-projeto

Estou fazendo um projeto a título de estudo para aplicar o que aprendi até agora com o Django. Minha dúvida é: qual a melhor maneira de segmentar o projeto em *apps*? Se quiserem dar um exemplo para que algo empírico seja captado, digamos que o projeto é de uma biblioteca, aonde haverão livros, autores, funcionários, aonde os que desejarem possam através de um cadastro registrar os livros, etc. Como vocês dividiriam esse projeto em *apps*?

Answer (score 3):

Não é possível responder de forma genérica, pois isso depende muito mais do domínio que está sendo modelado, bem como dos seus objetivos com o projeto.

A princípio, não há problema algum em se ter uma única *app* para o projeto inteiro. Se seu `models.py` está ficando grande demais, você pode quebrá-lo em arquivos menores. O mesmo vale para o `views.py`, etc:

```
app
|- __init__.py
|- urls.py
|- admin.py
|- models
|  |- __init__.py
|  |- a.py
|  |- b.py
|  |- c.py
|- views.py
```

Caso você faça isso, seu `models/__init__.py` deve importar todos os outros, de modo que o Django encontre seus modelos:

```
from .a import *
from .b import *
from .c import *
```

E cada modelo desses sub-módulos deve ter uma classe `Meta` indicando qual é a sua *app* (Fonte: [essa resposta no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/859222/520779)):

```
class Livro(models.Model):
    ...
    class Meta:
        app_label = 'minhaapp'
```

Se isso é ou não uma boa prática, é discutível. Mas é uma possibilidade.

E quando é que usar *apps* é definitivamente melhor?

1. Quando você pretende **reutilizar** parte do código em outro projeto, e parte dele não; uma *app* pode ser redistribuída separadamente do resto, e usada num outro contexto, para compor outro sistema.

   Se você acredita que um dia pode querer desenvolver um software para uma livraria, onde ainda existem livros, autores, etc, mas lá não se empresta livros, e sim vende, então vale a pena colocar as funcionalidades específicas da biblioteca (usuário fazer cadastro e registrar livro) separadamente da que simplesmente cataloga os livros.

   Da mesma forma, o código que você escrever para gerenciar os funcionários pode ser útil em ainda mais contextos, de modo que vale a pena ter uma *app* separada pra isso também.
2. Quando há uma **hierarquia de dependências** clara. A princípio, nada impede que a *app* `A` dependa da `B`, e a `B` também dependa da `A` (por exemplo, um modelo de `A` possui chave estrangeira pra um modelo de `B` e vice-versa). Mas isso traz certa dor-de-cabeça na hora de fazer os *imports*, ou na hora de decidir qual *app* incluir primeiro no `settings.py`. Se os modelos forem fortemente acoplados, melhor deixar tudo numa *app* só mesmo...

   Mas se você puder identificar um conjunto de modelos que só dependem [no máximo] uns dos outros, e de nenhum mais, e outro conjunto distinto que dependem um dos outros e de alguns modelos do primeiro conjunto, etc, fica mais organizado dividi-los em duas *apps* onde a primeira é dependência para a segunda. Criando e mantendo uma hierarquia simples você inclusive se força a manter seu projeto organizado e, sempre que surgir a "tentação" de introduzir uma dependência reversa, você se vê obrigado a repensar o seu design. Dá mais trabalho, sim, mas o resultado final compensa (a manutenabilidade do projeto fica mais fácil).

Na ausência de outras restrições, você pode fazer outras divisões mais ou menos arbitrárias, seguindo somente seu *feeling*. Se uma *app* tem modelos demais, por exemplo, você pode querer dividi-la para facilitar a organização. Ou se dois modelos parecem pertencer a domínios suficientemente distintos (ex.: livros vs. funcionários), você pode querer separá-los, ainda que existam poucos modelos no total (pode-se até mesmo criar *apps* sem *nenhum* modelo - só com código auxiliar, *views* por exemplo, ou também comandos). Esses são alguns critérios, mas poderiam haver outros. Não dá mesmo para enumerar todas as situações, mas os dois critérios acima já devem dar um bom guia.